# How to block notifications in Brave web browser?

Tags: notifications, brave

Like in Firefox and Chrome, Brave continually harasses you with site notification popups that read "This site wants to know your location. Allow/Deny?" or "This site wants to send you notifications. Allow/Deny?"

Since no user in the history of the Internet has ever wanted any of this notifications, most disable them in Firefox and Chrome. However, despite Brave being written with a respect for privacy, there doesn't appear to be any setting to disable these. It forces you to manually set it for every site. Is there any way around this by globally disabling them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These options can be found under the permissions section of the Site Settings menu. Both `chrome://settings/content/notifications` and `brave://settings/content/notifications` will bring you to the correct section, in which you can use the slider to choose between "Ask before sending (recommended)" and "Blocked".

[image: Brave settings]

Answer (score 3):

An additional info - There is one specific category of notifications in Brave browser which can't be disabled following the instruction in [Nathan's post](https://superuser.com/a/1469650/374397). Its name is Brave Rewards notifications. They can be disabled only when you turn-off **Brave Rewards** feature (Refer screenshot).

[image]